# Missing model behavior in nested implicitly bound route

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#customizing-missing-model-behavior), there is the following `missing()` method that can handle the fact that the model (attempted to be) retrieved is not found.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotoController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
 
Route::resource('photos', PhotoController::class)
        ->missing(function (Request $request) {
            return Redirect::route('photos.index');
        });
```

However, in the case of a nested resources, the route would look like so:

`Route::resource('users.photos', PhotoController::class)` which would resolve to a url like so:

```
/users/{user}/photos/{photo}
```

So, when `missing()` is trying to redirect to the photos index, the routing fails due to missing the `user` parameter. The parameter could be retrieved with `$request->route()->originalParameter('user')` but it seems like there could be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$request->route()->parameters('user')` if you want it to be less verbose.

Also, for nested resource routes, you might want to add an `if` statement to your `missing` Closure.

```
Route::resource('users.photos', PhotoController::class)
    ->missing(function (Request $request, Exception $e) {
        if (!$request->route()->parameters('user') instanceof Model) {
            // handle user not found
        } elseif (!$request->route()->parameters('photos') instanceof Model) {
            // handle photo not found
            return Redirect::route('user.photos.index', [$request->route()->parameters('user')]);
        }
    });
```